# Integrate DocuSign's EnvelopeViews:createSender REST api in python flask

Tags: python, flask, docusignapi

```
def sender_edit_view(self, authenticationMethod=None, envelopeId='',
                            returnUrl=''):
    if not self.account_url:
        self.login_information()
    url = '/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/edit' \
              .format(accountId=self.account_id,
                      envelopeId=envelopeId)
    if authenticationMethod is None:
        authenticationMethod = 'none'
    data = {
        'authenticationMethod': authenticationMethod,
        'returnUrl': returnUrl,
    }
    return self.post(url, data=data, expected_status_code=201)
```

pydocusign.exceptions.DocuSignException: DocuSign request failed: GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/9286679/envelopes/http://127.0.0.1:5000/views/edit returned code 404 while expecting code 201; Message:  ;

i want to redirect to sender view with the UI.

https://github.com/peopledoc/pydocusign/tree/master/pydocusign

trying to use from the above pydocusign.

Comment: I added the link to embedded sending

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please accept (check) the best answer for your question. Also, please upvote all useful answers that you read on the site. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pydocusign library is not from DocuSign. You're welcome to use it but we (DocuSign folks) can't provide advice about it.

Instead, I suggest that you check out the [DocuSign SDK for Python](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client).

There is an [example app](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-python-auth-code-grant) that includes many example workflows. [Workflow example 1](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-python-auth-code-grant/blob/master/app/eg001_embedded_signing.py) shows how to create an embedded signing ceremony.

#### Added

For embedded **sending**, see [Workflow example 11.](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-python-auth-code-grant/blob/master/app/eg011_embedded_sending.py)